Image clip using the container position in flutter
In this code one image container with black border and on this container one movable container using the movable container when click save button clip the image of using the movable container top and left position.
but when click on save button not clip image in proper way how to solve this?
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Image with Movable Container on Double Tap'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: MyImageWidget(),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,

            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyImageWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyImageWidgetState createState() => _MyImageWidgetState();
}

class _MyImageWidgetState extends State<MyImageWidget> {
  bool showContainer = false;
  // Offset containerPosition = Offset(50, 100);
  double top = 100;
  double left = 50;
  double width = 300;
  double hight = 200;
  double foretop = 100;
  double foreleft = 50;
  double forewidth = 100;
  double foreheight = 100;
  double cliptop = 0;
  double clipleft = 0;
  double clipheight = 200;
  double clipwidth = 300;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          showContainer = !showContainer;
        });
      },
      onDoubleTap: () {
        setState(() {
          showContainer = !showContainer;
        });
      },
      onPanUpdate: (details) {
        setState(() {
          foreleft += details.delta.dx;
          foretop += details.delta.dy;
        });
      },
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned(
              top: top,
              left: left,
        child:  Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(
                color: Colors.black, // Border color
                width: 2.0, // Border width
              ),
            ),
            child :ClipRect(
              clipper: MyCustomClipper( clipleft, cliptop, clipwidth, clipheight),
            child: Image.asset(
              'images/rose1.png', // URL to your image
              width: width, // Width of the image
              height: hight, // Height of the image
              fit: BoxFit.cover, // Adjust the image within the container
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
          if (showContainer)
            Positioned(
              left: foreleft,
              top: foretop,
              child: Container(
                width: forewidth,
                height: foreheight,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)),
              ),
            ),
          Positioned(
            bottom: 20,
            right: 20,
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  clipheight =  foreheight;
                  clipwidth = forewidth;
                  cliptop = foretop;
                  clipleft =  foreleft;
                  width = forewidth;
                  hight = foreheight;
                  top = foretop;
                  left = foreleft;
                 
                });
              },
              child: Text('Save'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
class MyCustomClipper extends CustomClipper<Rect> {
  // Define the left, top, width, and height of the clipping region
  final double left;
  final double top;
  final double width;
  final double height;

  MyCustomClipper(this.left, this.top, this.width, this.height);

  @override
  Rect getClip(Size size) {
    return Rect.fromLTWH(left, top, width, height);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Rect> oldClipper) {
    return true;
  }
}

In this code one image container with black border and on this container one movable container using the movable container when click save button clip the image of using the movable container top and left position.
but when click on save button not clip image in proper way how to solve this?



when click on save button image clip and the container border update.

but when click save button image is clip done. than i have to update border of image container. show image container border around the visible image area.

sorry i have no idea what you mean by that

i have add images what i can do. in the first image i have set movable container and click on save button.  see second image i have update image container but image not set fit in container some white space in the container

this code take a time for crop and i have add many other concepts.

take a time? everything takes a time - this is how you take a subimege by using drawImageRect - there is no other way

There seems to be an issue with how you're updating the clipping parameters.
update the clipping parameters (cliptop, clipleft, clipwidth, clipheight) based on the position and size of the movable container when the save button is clicked.
    onPressed: () {
  setState(() {
//Here update the clips
      cliptop = foretop - top;
    clipleft = foreleft - left;
    clipwidth = forewidth;
    clipheight = foreheight;
  });
},

Apply the clipping correctly in the ClipRect widget
ClipRect(
  clipper: MyCustomClipper(clipleft, cliptop, clipwidth, clipheight),
  child: Image.asset(
    'your image',
    width: width,
    height: hight,
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
  ),
),


it work for clip but when clip done than i have to update border of container only border show visible image portion.
